# CoffeeScript or plain JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, coffeescript

when the average ASP.net C# programmer (with very poor JavaScript knowledge other than scripting some hide() show() effects) would have to switch from building ASP.net WebForms apps to a RIA JavaScript application (client-server architecture like).

What would probably be less pain for him:

- Learn CoffeeScript and use it for "coding JavaScript"??
- Properly learn JavaScript and use that directly??

I'm thinking about

- Proper debugging
- Coding syntax
- ...

Does anyone have experiences in a similar scenario??

Comment: I'd say it's always good to understand the actual language. CoffeeScript might speed up things, but you will not get far if you don't understand JS.

Comment: @Felix That's what I think as well. So you'd rather start with JavaScript and then once devs get better knowledge possibly switch over to "accelerators" like CoffeeScript?

Comment: As a sidenote don't use WinForms for RIA development. @Juri arguably CoffeeScript is not an "accelerator". It's a style/preference choice not a "better" choice.

Comment: @Raynos Your right. No we won't use WinForms for RIA for sure ;)

Comment: Subjective questions like this tend to be migrated to Programmers these days. See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/72569/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-coffeescript/ and http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/72699/should-i-invest-time-learning-coffeescript.

Comment: @Trevor I know this question has in part a subjective character, but it is important to me and I guess others may be in a similar situation. Hence it might be quite valuable.

Comment: learning CoffeeScript has helped me learn much about JavaScript. Ideally the student will learn the tools and syntax that best project their logical constructs into functioning code no matter why language or library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had a pretty long discussion about that topic in the [Stackoverflow Javascript Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) over the past days. General conclusion was, that CoffeeScript is a nice tool which might create "ok" javascript code. However, if you know what you're doing you probably want to code directly in javascript without a 'higher level' language which semi compiles down to it.

I'm not really experienced with CoffeeScript so if I'm saying something wrong I'd be happy to get corrected. For instance, I can't tell how CoffeeScript reacts on ECMAscript3 to 5 (maybe even to 6) differences. Does CoffeeScript automatically create fallback code for each or does it just produce ES3 code ?

All those questions and doubts are one reason for me to go with plain Javascript as far as possible. If you not care so much whats going on under the hood and you need quick results, it's probably a good way to go.

Comment: Indeed that's what I'm thinking as well. (You don't happen to have a permalink to that discussion, don't you? Otherwise I'm going to pick it out myself.)  My issue is more that the dev's that are going to switch over will get trained in JavaScript 'cause their knowledge isn't at a high level enough. So presenting CoffeeScript there would probably not be appropriate, but rather just confusing I guess (also given the syntax differences to C#).

Comment: @Juri search JS chat for "CoffeeScript" there have been multiple discussion. And the only real way to avoid having your .NET devs learn JavaScript is to use SilverLight for your RIA.

Answer (score 11):

**TL;DR:** The best thing to do is Learn JavaScript.

**Books:**

- JavaScript: [The Good Parts](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748)
- CoffeeScript: [Smooth CoffeeScript](http://autotelicum.github.com/Smooth-CoffeeScript/)

**Cutting Corners:**

If you want to cut corners / have dead lines to hit look at [Script#](http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp) or other C# -> JS compilers.

**On CoffeeScript:**

However I disagree with @jAndy on parts. I believe CoffeeScript is stable enough to use.

You could learn from  which doesn't require JavaScript knowledge.

If you like the coffeescript use it. I prefer the JavaScript syntax so I use that.

**Learning RIA:**

I personally find that CoffeeScript vs JS is a matter of preference, you still have to learn HTML/CSS/DOM.

There is a lot more to RIA development then just knowing JavaScript.

**Problems with CoffeeScript:**

However there is a big problem with not learning JavaScript, Debugging coffeescript means debugging auto generated JavaScript and that is a pain if you have no knowledge.

**Personal Recommendation:** Learn ES5. Debugging without JS knowledge is a nightmare.

**JavaScript is not a bad language:**

Some people think JS is a horrible language, this reasons for this are mediocre implementations of ES3. But EcmaScript5 is a solid and lovely language. People confuse Browser compliance and browser bugs with the language. I'd personally be tempted to say learning ES5 is nicer then learning CS

Comment: I never said it's not stable :p

Comment: @jAndy if you question / do not trust the compiler that is CoffeeScript then your stating it's not stable

Comment: +1 for the link to Smooth CoffeeScript. It's not really for me personally, but rather my objections are related to the other devs that switch over to JavaScript from a Asp.net C# environment...

Comment: @Raynos: I question / do not trust in code which is generated in general. It's all about controll to me. Secondly, I totally disagree in Javascript beeing a horrible language, it's actually a great language not just because of ES5+

Comment: @jAndy your right. I meant buggy implementations of ES3 like JavaScript 1.2 and JScript 3. Cleaned up

Comment: @Raynos: Any good resources (books, links,...) about RIA development?

Comment: RIA web app development with JavaScript mainly. Currently I'm reading this book and it's excellent. Can just recommend it: http://oreilly.com/catalog/0636920018421

Comment: Btw, Mozilla's SourceMap is going to make debugging of CoffeeScript much smoother https://wiki.mozilla.org/DevTools/Features/SourceMap

Answer (score 6):

I'm the author of [CoffeeScript: Accelerated JavaScript Development](http://pragprog.com/book/tbcoffee/coffeescript), which is just coming out in print. The approach I took in writing that book—in contrast to [Smooth CoffeeScript](http://autotelicum.github.com/Smooth-CoffeeScript/), which others in this thread have mentioned—is that I try to teach readers both CoffeeScript and JavaScript. My opinion on the "Which should I learn?" question has always been: **You shouldn't learn CoffeeScript without learning JavaScript.**

Debugging is one good, and obvious, reason to understand JavaScript. A less obvious reason is that as a CoffeeScript developer in the real world, you'll be relying on JavaScript libraries (like jQuery). You need to be able to understand the documentation for those libraries (and ideally, their source code).

The good news is that the two languages are very, very close to each other. CoffeeScript has no standard library of its own; it doesn't modify prototypes; and output is in the same order as input (except for very minor exceptions like being able to write `f() if x` instead of `if x then f()`). So if you already have a *little* JavaScript knowledge—if you're one of the many developers who doesn't entirely understand what `this` means, or how prototypal inheritance works—then I think you should start learning CoffeeScript. Along the way, you'll become a better JavaScripter.

Think of CoffeeScript and JavaScript as two dialects of the same language. Achieve fluency in one, and you'll find that the other comes naturally.

Comment: But what about debugging? Assume I start teaching my devs JavaScript, but as a development "language" I define that we use CoffeeScript. My fear is that they won't join in as they already have to switch from a well known C# environment with a excellent vs2010 IDE and then they have to learn a new syntax (CoffeeScript - although it's quite simple) and then they don't have very good debugging support (as you debug JavaScript and code CoffeeScript)...Guess they would kick me in the *** ;) So at the moment I'm quite of the idea of starting with JavaScript and then eventually later use CoffeeScript

Answer (score 3):

CoffeeScript provides shorter syntax, some syntatic sugar and help to avoid few javascript traps - like 0 == "".

That's it. Nothing more. No amazing, mind-blowing concepts, no radically different approaches. 
If you are a good javascripter, you can, say, improve your efficiency by 10-15% using coffeescript. You will be always need to compile you sources, but this is not a big deal. Look, for example, at portlets creators, they are compiling sources each time they want to see changes. And the world is still spinning around :) With some clever approaches, you wouldn't feel uncomfortable.

But nevertheless, it is way better to begin from javascript. Coffeescript is nice, but there is a huge distance from acknowledging it as a production standard. I can even imagine  situation when coffeescript development will be abandoned. It can cause you  some (not big, but annoying) troubles, if you'll have by that moment big ancestry of coffeescript code.

Besides, coding in coffescript will not save you from duty to learn lot of different things - about DOM, about events, about basic objects and so on. I repeat, it is way, waaay better to learn javascript. And then, when you already will have some experience as javascripter, it's up to you to decide whether you need to use any specific js compiler or not. It's like smoking, you know. It is your choice but you should be adult )))

Answer (score 0):

my advice to people would be to jump on coffeescript early. you have to compile it to js anyways so you'll see what you write compiles to and since most answers to your questions will be in javascript, you'll naturally learn both at the same time. and utilize this tool: http://js2coffee.org/. trying to use coffeescript off the bat will make you a better a javascripter, i see a lot of back end developers migrating to javascript and they write really poor code, chances are they weren't writing great backend code either, but none the less, if they were they were writing coffeescript they would clean up their code, and start out writing their code naturally better.

we are in a great field / especially security wise, but stay current, highly recommended adopting the future technologies the fact that coffeescript ships with RubyOnRails now, eventhough I don't use RubyOnRails was enough for me to adopt, because if a project comes up where I have to use it, I am not starting from scratch.

thinks of all the money people earned jumping on C# early, RoR early, JQuery early.. there is a large portion of jQuery users who never bother to learn how to write their own plugin which is incredibly easy to do, and only incorporate others, or their idea of code reuse is copy and paste.

It doesnot take much to get ahead in this field. Learn the language that makes things most efficient, and keep you from starting bad habits, then learn to create extensible plugins or an any opensource project, and you'll never hurt for work.

in short it will be unavoidable learning javascript if you try to push what you can do as a developer start with coffeescript for a leg up on your peers competing for the same jobs.